# C# .NET - How can I split string with a tab separator?

Tags: c#, .net, string, tabs, split

I have this string in my code:

```
string test = @"aaaaa   aaaaa   aaaaa   bbbb    ttttt   tttttt
33333   44444   777777   77777   88888   8888    8888    88888   88888
wwwww   wwwww   wwwwww   wwwww   wwwww   wwwwww";
```

And here is my code spliting string by new line character and tab.

```
foreach (var line in test.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
{
    foreach (var lineItem in line.Split('\t'))
    {                        
    }
}
```

In first interation of first loop **line** variable is *"aaaaa   aaaaa   aaaaa   bbbb    ttttt   tttttt"* and this is correct, but in seconds loop first interation variable **lineItem** is the same, it doesn't split this string with tab separator. Why it's happening?

Comment: Your sample string is separated not by tabs, but by "   " (3 x space) symbols. Are you sure your real string separated by tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because the `tabs` are not tabs in your `string test` - see this:

[image] 
The first line is what i generated myself from MS Excel. Use regex to correctly represent any whitespace char (even for Unicode escape sequences)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s");
string[] bits = regex.Split(line);
```

Comment: Ok, when I add \t between words in test string, it works ok, BUT in my method I will get string that looks like test string, without those '\t', for example:
John has a bike      Anna has a car   
Mike has a plane      John has a dog

How can I split it? i need each sentence separetely, lineItem should be:John has a bike. And all i know those sentences will be separated by tab.

Comment: In that case use regex to split for any whitespace char - see my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your string has tab characters ? try using `Split()` it will split by tab and white-space:

```
foreach (var lineItem in line.Split())
{                        
}
```